Auth0 - Session Loose (iPhone/iPad)
In a Angular App, When open a link with target=“_blank” or Refresh the page it is redirecting to Login page.
After click on login (Powered by Auth0) it recognizes that there is a session and perform an auto-login (No Username/Password needed to enter). but never redirects to the URL it was pointing.
In Mac it works fine. It takes you directly to the URL intended to open without stopping and enforcing you to login again.
